# Set new image size only works when image is moved

Tags: java, android, image-resizing

I want to resize the image (overlayButton) when I click on my "ok" button. However, I don't know what to put in my setSize () method. I tried "overlayButton.setScaleX(size)" and "overlayButton.setScaleY(size)" but that does nothing. Here is my code. As it is, my image resizes but only once I have dragged it.

```
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                seekTxt.setText(Integer.toString(progress) + "%");
                overlayButton.getLayoutParams().width = progress;
                overlayButton.getLayoutParams().height = progress;
                overlayButton.requestLayout();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }
        });

        seekDialog.show();
    }
}

public void sizeOK(View view) {
    if (overlayButton != null) {
        setSize(size);
        seekDialog.dismiss();
    } else {
        seekDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

public int getSize() {
    return Math.round((float) size / 300 * 300);
}

public void setSize(int newSize) {
    size = Math.round((float) newSize / 300 * 300);
    overlayButton.
}
```

I'd be grateful for a pointer as to what to put in that setSize() method. Thanks!

**Edit with solution:**
The drawable needed to be refreshed. The solution is therefore:

```
    public void sizeOK(View view) {
    if (overlayButton != null) {
        setSize(size);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) overlayButton.getLayoutParams();
        wm.updateViewLayout(overlayButton, params);
        seekDialog.dismiss();
    } else {
        seekDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is certainly related to the refreshment of your image. It is certainly automatically triggered when you drag the image but not when you simply resize it. Try to find some "invalidate" function which would cause the system to redraw you image.

Comment: Thanks! Bizarrely, I also have a seekbar for opacity levels, and that refreshes fine when I click "ok"...